# How to copy values from one excel range to another using formula reference in Excel using Office.js

Tags: office-js

Suppose in Sheet1 I have a range (from B2:C3), having values [[1, 2], [3, 4]]. Now I want to copy this range to another sheet (Sheet2) starting at D5.
That is, In Sheet2 I have a range D5:E6 with values

[[='Sheet1'!B2, ='Sheet1'!B3],

[='Sheet1'!C2, ='Sheet1'!C3]].

How can I Do this in Excel using Office.js

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [range.copyFrom](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/excel/range.md#copyfromsourcerange-range-or-rangeareas-or-string-copytype-rangecopytype-skipblanks-bool-transpose-bool) API. This API is in Preview, so please make sure to install the latest Office Insiders fast and use our BETA CDN endpoint https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Here is a [script lab snippet](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/bef8c306b5e6cd32175407e49aa301e1) that shows how to use it.

Here is some sample code (using TypeScript)

```js
async function run() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {

        context.workbook.worksheets.
            getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A5")
            .copyFrom("H5:H8", Excel.RangeCopyType.all, true, true);
      

        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

. You can paste, values, formulas, format or all.